# If I can see my password in Fiddler Webform session, does it mean it's sending plain text?

Tags: passwords, fiddler, plaintext

If I can see my password in Fiddler Webform session, does it mean it's sending plain text?? 
Or how can I know if the website is sending passwords as plain text?

Comment: You should really accept Eugene's answer here.

Answer (score 5):

**If you can see it, and the protocol is HTTP, then it is being sent as plain text**. But even if you can't see it as plain text, it doesn't mean it's safely encrypted and might be easily recoverable, like is the case with [HTTP Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) (unless used in combination with HTTPS, see below).

Basic authentication would look something like

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```

which is not plain text, but only base 64 encoded, i.e. straightforward to decode back to plain text.

However, **if the protocol is HTTPS, then what you see as plain text is completely encrypted** to any sniffer between your machine and the server. This includes the full http request and response: Url, Http headers and Http body. All that can be "sniffed" are the IP addresses and ports used, and normally the domain name, as your browser got the IP address by doing a (non-encrypted) call to DNS.

This requires that you configure Fiddler to decrypt HTTPS for you, which requires you 'OK' Fiddler's certificate so that it can do what amounts to a "friendly" man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: So if I lost my phone and have not locked the login, it is super easy for someone to setup "friendly man in the middle" attack and possibly access data from all my apps. Is this a fair assumption?

Comment: At an app level, one way to block this would be to encrypt the app data before sending it over https POST, and then decrypt it server side. Or is there something more straightforward ?